# Issue downloading and running PerformanceAnalytics in R

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am starting to learn portfolio analysis in R using the PerformanceAnalytics package, and I was wondering if anyone else has had issues downloading it. I end up getting the following error:

```
require("PerformanceAnalytics")

Loading required package: PerformanceAnalytics
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ in 
loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘quadprog’
Warning message:
package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ was built under R version 3.4.3
```

I tried downloading quadprog, but that didn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do `.libPaths()` and remove the `PerformanceAnalytics` and `quadprog` packages.
2. Upgrade R to the newest version (should run on R > 3.0.0. but this may cause a problem).

Two options then.

1. `install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics, dependencies = TRUE)`
2. Install the packages step by step: Install `quadprog` first and then install `PerformanceAnalytics`